# How to scroll to a certain point in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Below I have a line of code that scrolls to a certain point in a `UIScrollView`. However once it has scrolled there it does not allow me to scroll back up.

```
[scroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,500) animated:NO];
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `it does not allow me to scroll back up`?

Comment: @Arkadiusz Holko Allow me to drag back up the uiscrollview and for it to scroll back up. Because at the moment once i have set the content offset it does not let me scroll beach up it sticks to that position. however it does allow me to scroll down.

Comment: What is the content size before you do anything, and after you scroll? What scroll view delegate methods are called when you try to scroll up?

Comment: The content Size is currently: x= 320 y= 1,700 and these are all of the delegate methods. However i am currently not using any of them:        `– scrollViewDidScroll:`
`– scrollViewWillBeginDragging:`
`– scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`
`– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`
`– scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:`
`– scrollViewDidScrollToTop:`
– scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:`
– scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`

Answer (score 3):

I use this. The button calls this method. Should work well.

```
- (void)downExecute:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"scroll down");

    CGFloat currentOffset = _scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    CGFloat newOffset;    
    newOffset = currentOffset + self.view.bounds.size.height;

    [UIScrollView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^(void) {
        [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, newOffset)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

did you try using UIScrollView method **scrollRectToVisible:**
Here is an example

```
- (void)goToPage:(int)page animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scroller.frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scroller.frame.size;
    [self.scroller scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:animated];

    // update the scroll view to the appropriate page
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this kind of problem because I called this method from viewDidLayoutSubviews(). Check where are you calling it from. When I moved the logic to viewDidAppear() everything worked as expected. Hope it helps, cheers.